# Is there a way to remove the GalliumOS greeter/opening graphics?

Tags: boot, grub, gui, lxdm

Basically, I'd really love to be able to just have the command line be the way I boot into Gallium, but the main way I tried was a little wonky. I deleted LXDM entirely, which not only didn't delete the little GalliumOS animation at the beginning there, but when I booted into the GUI with startx after signing in, not only was it a desktop without any of my settings or visual modifications, but the mouse pointer was unresponsive.

I reinstalled lxdm and now login to the stock greeter again, so I'm back to square one.

The command prompt would just seriously go way better with the rest of my aesthetic choices for how I'm customizing my GUI.

So, is there a way to do this? Do I edit grub? If so, how exactly?

There's gotta be a way. Seems like there should be, right?

Comment: Maybe rebuild your initramfs without Plymouth?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but could you elaborate? Sorry, I'm in the strange netherworld of having a good handle on some of this, but I still have some pretty big holes in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/) is responsible for displaying that splash screen you see. It's started early in the Linux boot process (the [initial ramdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk)).

As GalliumOS is based on Xubuntu, see [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot) for instructions on how to go about disabling it.

You may also have to disable a systemd service like `lxdm-plymouth.service`.

Comment: Actually, Plymouth is a Linux program, it's not invoked by bootloader. You might have a misunderstanding of what a bootloader is.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Edited to correct